# Eslint version automatically downgrading on init

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm installing ESLint on a project with the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint@latest
```

which gets me the 4.1.1 version of the package.

After i init it with the command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init
```

I follow the instructions to use Airbnb codestyle and i get downgraded to version 3.19.0.

How can i get it to use version 4.0.0 atleast?

Comment: Yikes, thanks for finding this! I just reproduced it and reported the bug to our issue tracker: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8870

Comment: I'll keep an eye on the issue then, thanks for the answer.

Comment: This has been fixed! See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/8911

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working as intended.

Quoting @kaicataldo on github:

"A number of breaking changes were introduced on the plugin authoring side of things in ESLint v4. Installing ESLint v4 with a plugin that has not been updated yet could result in a broken installation, so the behavior you're seeing is intentional to ensure that everything works together."